# Django: Using ".first()" on a related queryset triggers queries despite "prefetch_related". Is there a workaround?

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize some querysets in my Django code by using `prefetch_related`.

However, I've realized that if elsewhere in the code, a queryset function such as `first`, `last`, `latest` etc.. is called on a related queryset, a query is triggered regardless, effectively nullifying the optimization.

e.g.

```
class Client(models.Model):  
    # [...]

    @property
    def latest_order(self):
        self.orders.latest('ordered_at') # Order is a Many-to-one related obj
```

Using `Client.objects.prefetch_related('orders')` is not gonna be useful and `latest_order` will still trigger a query for each `Client`.

Is there a way around this without altering the `Client` model's property? Otherwise if that's the best solution, what's the best way to retain the functionality `latest_order`?

The only way I can think of is to just to replicate `latest` functionality but in memory (via the `sorted` function), however this means that I lose out on being able to do this operation database-side if it's advantageous (e.g. I'm just looking at 1 client with A LOT of orders).

Comment: How do you expect `.latest()` to work without query?

Comment: well it could theoretically run on the prefetched queryset instead of going to the database to run there

Comment: The problem is that the `latest()` call creates a new QuerySet based on the previous (executed) QuerySet. To reuse the prefetched data Django would need to have logic that understands the relation beween the QuerySets in general and for every database (their reactions are not always the same). That would be a task of a DBMS and not a web framework. Simple processing of data can of cause been done in Python code.